# Excluding C# scripts from AssetBundle in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm currently building an application with Unity3D for the WinRT platform. I have 2 projects:

1. The main project that can download / load an AssetBundle and open a scene from it.
2. A project with multiple scenes that generates AssetBundles which can be loaded by project 1.

Whenever I build the application, all scripts are being compiled, and ultimately excluded from the AssetBundle. This is exactly what I want because this way I can force that project 2 can make use of Shared Scripts defined by project 1, but not create custom scripts. (Just give them the same name and Unity will automatically load the correct script when you load the AssetBundle in project 1).

However, when I use async/await code in Project2, or make use of some other WinRT functions, I'm running into compilation errors when I compile the AssetBundles. I don't really understand why since ultimately the scripts won't be included anyway. (If I load scripts that are defined in Project2 but not in Project1 I see a "script missing" error, which is what I would expect).

So basically, what I want, is to be able to create an AssetBundle, with links to the scripts, but without compiling the scripts (since the compiled scripts will exist in Project1).

I also tried defining the "UNITY_EDITOR" attribute (under Edit > Project Settings > Player) (since my async/await code uses that to omit parts of the code during compilation time), but that results in even more errors where it can't find certain namespaces anymore, e.g.:
`using UnityEngine.VR.WSA.Sharing;` shows error: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Sharing' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.VR.WSA'.`

Does anybody have an idea on how to resolve/work around this issue?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand fully what you mean. Perhaps you can make use of virtual functions for whatever it is you need, and then during runtime when you've loaded the scrips you replace those functions with whatever projects scripts functions you need. Kind of like how OpenVR does with its SDK? Basically creating an abstraction layer between the two. Just an idea.

Comment: Which version of unity do you use? Are both projects using the same version?

Comment: Script missing errors can be caused because the hash of the scripts doesn't match. Hash is built from class name and its public serialized members, so if you have differences between public members because of defines, it can be the cause of different script hashes. You can check them inside corresponding .meta files for scripts.

Comment: Also AFAIK unity doesn't support async/await, how did you manage to use them in any of project?

Comment: @IvanFateev, both projects indeed use the same version. Please note thought that the problem isn't that the scripts are missing. The problem is, is that Unity still tried to compile the scripts even though I just want them to be added as a reference. (So the Hash of the scripts do match, I just want Unity to skip the compilation).

Regarding your question about async/await, for example the Hololens has written some extensions for Unity which allow you to use async/await. (See the Hololens github: https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity)

Comment: @Devedse isn't that a similar problem ? https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/2785/still-having-a-problem-with-asynchronous-calls-using-unity5-40f3-htp-with-hololens maybe you should rely on #if WINDOWS_UWP define? Also note that UNITY_EDITOR is defined automatically by unity editor, but when you build application for specific platofrm, UNITY_EDITOR should be false

Comment: The problem  is somewhat similar indeed. However that would require me to do quite some changes in the libraries that I am using.  I'd rather just completely exclude them.